# SyntaxError: cannot assign to list comprehension?

Tags: python

My code:

```
def function():
    resources, bufferViews, accessors = parse_gltf(fname)

    display(resources)

    display(bufferViews)

    display(accessors)

    ds = []
    idx_vertex = -1
    idx_normals = -1
    idx_textures = -1
    idx_meshes = -1

    for j in range(len(accessors)):
        accessor = accessors[j]

        if accessor.min:
            idx_vertex = j

        d = parse_accessor(accessor, resources, bufferViews)
        ds.append(d)

        if d.shape[1] == 3:
            idx_normals = j

        if d.shape[1] == 2:
            idx_textures = j

        if d.shape[1] == 1:
            idx_meshes = j

    return idx_vertex, idx_normals, idx_textures, idx_meshes, [e.shape for e in ds]

if __name__ == "main":
    idx_vertex, idx_normals, idx_textures, idx_meshes, [e.shape for e in ds] = function()
    display(ds[idx_vertex])
```

Basically, I want to be able to return the values idx_vertex, idx_normals, idx_textures, idx_meshes and be able to assign them in the ds array. However, I get "SyntaxError: cannot assign to list comprehension" when I try to achieve this. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error is pretty clear; a list comprehension cannot be on the left-hand side of an assignment. List comprehensions *construct* lists; you can't use them to unpack an existing list.

Comment: `idx_vertex, idx_normals, idx_textures, idx_meshes, shapes = function()`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the list comprehension in a variable in your start routine:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    idx_vertex, idx_normals, idx_textures, idx_meshes, shape_list = function()
    display(ds[idx_vertex])
```

Your `function` function is already returning the list `[e.shape for e in ds]`

LE: Edited according to MattDMO's comment

Comment: That's weird. I tried this, but it doesn't display anything? I also tried changing "display" to just print, and I also did a test where I change it to print("g"), and it still doesn't print anything.

Comment: It needs to be `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Now it says ds isn't defined.

Comment: Can you share the full code? Where did you import ds, display, parse_accessor and parse_gltf from?